# How to loop through table td and update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through a table's td and update each td based on an array:

```
var person = []; //each array stores a person's name, height, and weight

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

  $("table th").each(function(){
    $(this).text(person[i].name);
  });

  $("table td").each(function() {
    $(this).text(person[i].height + '/' + person[i].weight);
  });

}
```

However, this ends up storing the last value of the array in the td... I need help in looping through the td's based on their index...  can someone help?

Comment: can you have the array and the html mark up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems is that you are iterating over the `th/td`, so, every time it iterate the first `for` loop, then with `jQuery` you iterate all `th/td` and update the content with the current `index` of the outer `for` value. Don't know if you understand all that but i will give you an example of how to solved.

```
var person = []; //each array stores a person's name, height, and weight

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $("table th:eq("+i+")").text(person[i].name);
  $("table td:eq("+i+")").text(person[i].height + '/' + person[i].weight);
}
```

I don't know what is your expected final result, but the code i wrote get exactly the `th/td` at the same index you are currently iterating over.

Or, if you are sure you have the same amount of `td/th` that exist in your array, probably this is ok for you

```
$("table th").each(function(index){
  $(this).text(person[index].name);
});
```

but it can fail in a few ways depending on the content of the `person` array

hope it help

Comment: @user1547174 glad it helped you, so, is this the accepted answer?